# Can a spell keep track of its target if the target changes controller?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I'm in a multiplayer game. I cast [Assassin's Trophy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAssassin%27s%5d%2b%5bTrophy%5d) targeting opponent A's [Sol Ring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSol%20Ring%5d). Opponent B controlls [Aladdin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAladdin%5d) and responde by activating the ability targeting the same Sol Ring. Aladdin's ability resolves and opponent B gains control of Sol Ring.

Will Assassin's Trophy fizzle or will it still destroy the Sol Ring but allow opponent B to fetch the basic land instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. An object that changes controllers is still the same object, so a spell that targeted it will continue to target it.

Assassin's Trophy checks who controls the targeted permanent as the spell resolves, so in this scenario opponent B will fetch the basic land.

Comment: Note this can cause it to fizzle due to an illegal target (say if the same player both cast assassin's trophy and used Aladdin - then the opponent controls requirement won't be met anymore)